# Drop table if exists in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql-server-ce

I've looked all around the internet and I can't find a working solution? I know there's no `IF` in SQL Server CE, so I'm trying other different stuff, but no luck. Does anybody know a solution that does work?

Comment: What about a plain `DROP` and handle the exception that is thrown if it does not exist?

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann I was thinking that too, but that will be my last resort, I want to discard the possibility of doing through SQL first. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

How about querying the information schema and see if the table exists, in code, and if it does then you drop it?

You could use a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'
```

And if it exists you fire the `DROP` statement.

Comment: How would the whole query look like? I can't use 'IF' so I'm not sure what would I have to do after the select.

Comment: @Carlo, sorry, I thought you were interacting with the database through some code written in, C# for example, and that you could query the database through C# and have your `if`s there. If that is not the case, then, as you said yourself, there is no `IF` in SQLCE. I thought you were looking for alternative approaches.

Comment: We're trying to run SQL scripts to update the database version. In this version we need to drop a table. The reason we don't do it in C# is because we don't want to change the code that updates the DB every time we change the DB version, we just want to add a SQL script file that C# knows how to run based on the DB version.

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL CE doesn't handle conditional logic (or dynamic SQL, or `TRY/CATCH`), I don't know that there's a way to do it in pure SQL; you may have to have some logic in your C# program instead of just having it be a dumb controller of a SQL script where all the brains live.

Some related questions with equally bad news:

[How can I check whether a table exists in SQL Server CE 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316336/how-can-check-if-the-table-exist-are-not-in-sql-server-ce-3-5)

["If not exists" fails on SQL CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652867/if-not-exists-fails-on-sql-ce)

Comment: Alternately, if you can generate sql to be executed, you could `SELECT @var = 'DROP TABLE ' + table_name FROM information_schema WHERE table_name = @tablename` or something

Comment: No, no dynamic SQL in SQL CE. You can't even say `DECLARE` apparently.

Comment: But hey, you can turn `IDENTITY` on and off using `ALTER TABLE` - so I'm going to switch to SQL CE. :-)